# Running on Windows 8 caused hebrew sub menus to open to wrong direction

Tags: wpf, windows-8, menu, right-to-left

I have a strange issue -

RTL menu. 
in Windows 7 the submenus were to open from the right side and extend to the left 
in Windows 8 the submenus opens from the left side of each menu item and extend to the right - like in english menu.

What happened (no changes in code)....

Answer (score 0):

Could this be related to tablet setting in Windows 8? Since by default, Win8 seems to assume that you are using touch controls and you are right-handed, which makes the menus open on the left side, so that your finger does not block the view of the menu (even if you don't actually touch the screen to bring up the menu).

Try looking at this web site: http://www.articulate.com/support/kb_article.php?product=ve9&id=jtroshyyzr8s